# What is the space complexity of my code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, space-complexity

I am comfortable enough with time complexities, but not yet with space complexities.  I had the following question about space complexity:

```
unordered_set<int> s;
for(auto& i : nums)
    s.insert(i);
```

As per my understanding, the space complexity of the above code snippet is `O(n)` (`n` is the number of elements in the input vector `nums`) because I create the set outside the for loop and insert at max `n` elements in it.

However, if I would have created the set inside the for loop like:

```
for(auto& i : nums) {
    unordered_set<int> s;
    s.insert(i);
}
```

then in this case, would my space complexity again be `O(n)`?  I understand what I am doing is different (creating a new set each time and inserting only one element in it), but I am just curious about the space complexity.

In short, does the space complexity depend only upon how many elements are inserted in the data structure, or also upon how many data structures are used (like creating them in a loop).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case space complexity is `O(1)` and first case it is `O(n)`.

#### Second case..

If you consider the second case in the loop each time you declare a local `unordered_set` and then you push 1 element. And then that is not used and again another iteration. At most `1` or constant amount of space is used.

#### First case..

In the first case you take a `set` and then insert elements. At most `n` elements you insert. That's why `O(n)`.

#### Some definition

> For every size of the input the algorithm will take the some amount
>   of space. Without over complicating you can say that maybe it is used
>   store the output or some work that you need to do intermediately. How
>   many data structures you use is not the concern rather **the space used
>   by them is**.

---

*space complexity deals with finding out how much (extra)space would be required by the algorithm with change in the input size.*

---

Now lets check one thing suppose you increase your number of input in first case from `n=100` to `n=100000` then what will the extra memory that you will need. As you will be seeing that it increases linearly. (Before `100` inputs `100` elements of set now `100000`).

In the second case, do you need it? You are always using only `1` space.(Constant amount of space). And then you discard it. And in new iteration you work with another space. At once only `1` element is there. So whatever be the input it will always be same.

To be more clear, if you use in each iteration you insert `3` elements it doesn't change the space complexity..this will still be `O(1)` time complexity denoting that it uses constant amount of space (irrespective of the input size).

Comment: Thank you, but am more curious about the last part of my question - "In short..."

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela If you are storing elements each to their own individual data structure, then you will have just as many data structures to store which comes back around to the initial problem. The same is true no matter how you distribute your elements in various structure. You'll have to store those structures somehow. Storage complexity must account for all data structures your algorithm needs to use.

Comment: But mathematically speaking in terms of number of bytes, wouldn't both consume the exact same number?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela.: On which case? How are you even considering the number of data structures? I can use one array `2n` elemnts and `n` array of 2 elements -- the time complexity in both vase is `O(2n)~O(n)`

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela.: Check the answer..it explains clearly the doubts

Comment: @coderredoc, thank you for the edits.  It cleared up the things for me.

Comment: It's worth highlighting that O(1) isn't because it uses 1 item, but because it uses a constant amount.  One wouldn't say that it was O(5) because it adds 5 integers; it would still be O(1) because the number of times the loop is done doesn't change the size.  Nice answer otherwise though - almost like you've answered before ;o).

Answer (score 2):

Space complexity tells you how much memory your algorithm is using.

In the second case you're only inserting one element into `s`. Right after that `s` goes out of scope and you start a new iteration. This means you're actually only using one memory unit at a time. Memory usage will not increase with `n`. Thus you have `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case your complexity is `O(1)`.
Each iteration will use the `set` only once, and then it will be freed.

In general, the complexity depends on the total space your program requires.
In your case you will use `n` times set of size 1, but it will not accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, each `unordered_set` ceases to exist after the loop body ends. A sensible implementation will re-use the same space for all the sets, and they only ever contain a single element.

If you use that as your space complexity metric, then the first case has `O(n)` additional space required, and the second case has `O(1)` additional space required

Comment: And what if the metric is the number of bytes consumed?  Also, could you kindly let me know the usual metric?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela, The usual metric is space used at a single point in time rather than the number and size of allocations.

Answer (score 0):

The space complexity is a measure of how the amount of required storage for your algorithm scales up in relation to your input size.

Assuming you insert `n` unique integers, `std::unordered_map` will indeed have to allocate enough storage to store `n` nodes, in addition to some constant values that are not affected by the number of integers you insert into it. Therefore, the space complexity would indeed be O(n).

In your second example, regardless of how many integers are in `num`, you will always allocate enough storage for one integer in a `std::unordered_set`. Therefore, your space complexity is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

From a complexity point of view, the storage supply is limitless, and all that matters is how much of it you're using simultaneously.

Consider the problem of measuring X buckets of water.
It makes no differences to the space complexity whether you

- Have one bucket that you fill, then empty, then fill again, then empty, ..., or
- Fill one bucket and discard the bucket, then fill another bucket and throw that away, ...

since you're always using at most one bucket at any given time.
The buckets themselves don't count towards the complexity, only the amount of them you're simultaneously holding.

On the other hand, if you had not one, but X buckets that you fill (perhaps you want to save the water for the oncoming drought), the space complexity would be O(X).